# How to combine SELECT and INSERT commands into a non existent table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, sql

How does one combine the `SELECT` and `INSERT INTO` commands and insert the results into a temporary table in SQL Server?

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable 
    SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: did you read your question? it's ambiguos..

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what I asked!

Comment: Seeing as you got a comment saying it is ambiguous, it is clear others don't think it is!

Comment: Well I don't know any other way to ask it! Please let me know which part is ambiguous and I'll clarify that bit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got two options. First one is to create your temp table and then use `INSERT INTO` ... `SELECT`, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
  Col1 ...
);

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT * FROM OtherTable;
```

The second option is to insert directly in a new temp table:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    #temp
FROM    OtherTable;
```

Big difference is that using method 1, you need to specify all the columns in your temp table in advance. Method 2 gives you a temp table that automatically has all the columns of your `OtherTable`.

Answer (score 6):

You want to insert into a table that doesn't yet exist? Your syntax was close. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx).

```
SELECT * INTO #BrandNewTempTable FROM MyTable
```

Comment: interesting that I did not know, nice one

Comment: One question. Can this syntax be used in MySql as well?

Comment: @EdwinDrood - A quick Google shows the syntax has been supported by MySQL since version 3.23 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your temporary table needs have the same fields of your origin table

If not you need specify all fields like code below:

```
INSERT INTO TEMPORARY_TABLE (field1, field1, field1)
SELECT (field1, field1, field1) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```