# INSERT sql statement combined with SELECT and WHERE

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert these values into a database, however, the INSERT and WHILE clause are incompatible with each other. Does anybody have any ideas how I could achieve my desired results in a different manner.

```
public boolean updateAns()
{
    boolean success=true;
    DBController db=new DBController();
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql="INSERT INTO kioskSurveyAns(survey_qn1,survey_qn2,survey_qn3) VALUES('"+radioText+"','"+radioText1+"','"+radioText2+"')SELECT survey_qn1,survey_qn2,survey3 FROM kioskSurveyAns WHERE survey_nric='"+nric+"'";

    if (db.updateRequest(sql) == 1)
    success = true;
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486550/how-to-combine-select-and-insert-commands-into-a-non-existent-table-in-sql-serve) help ?

Comment: you can update the row instead.

Comment: **You are making a big mistake here!** Never create an SQL query by concatenating user-provided strings. Otherwise your application will be vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement, there should be no `VALUES` keyword on it because the value that will be inserted came from the `SELECT` statement. eg

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tableX
WHERE....
```

but looking back on your query, you want to **UPDATE** the rows based on the values of the controls. right?

```
UPDATE kioskSurveyAns
SET    survey_qn1 = 'rad1',
       survey_qn2 = 'rad2',
       survey_qn3 = 'rad3'
WHERE  survey_nric= = 'richere'
```

As a sidenote, the statement is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please do parameterized your query using `PreparedStatements`

- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I tried to use UPDATE statement, however the data was not recorded. I think its because there were no data recorded previously.

Comment: the only records that will be updated is when the value you are searching matches on this column `survey_nric`

Comment: I insert null value into database first then update it. However, I cannot update the null value in database to a new value. I used the update statement but it does not work. Any guides?

Comment: INSERT INTO kioskSurveyAns(survey_nric,survey_phNo,survey_ans1,survey_ans2,survey_ans3,survey_ans4,survey_ans5,survey_ans6,survey_ans7,survey_ans8,survey_ans9,survey_ans10,survey_ans11,survey_ans12)";
  sql+="VALUES ('"+nric+"','"+phNo+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"','"+null+"')";

Comment: and update : "UPDATE kioskSurveyAns SET survey_ans4='"+radioText+"' ,survey_ans5='"+radioText1+"' ,survey_ans6='"+radioText2+"' WHERE survey_nric='"+nric+"'";